# Xamarin Carousel View - Binding not succesfull

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I'm not sure but i spent already 1 day with this problem.

I try to bind a Collection to the Xamarin Forms Carousel.

XAML Code:

```
<cv:CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding MainSlider}"  x:Name="carousel"   >
       <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                  <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
           </DataTemplate>
       </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
   </cv:CarouselView>
```

Xamarin Forms

```
public class SliderItem
     {
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

...

```
public ObservableCollection<SliderItem> MainSlider { get; set; }

...

 InitializeComponent();

        MainSlider = new ObservableCollection<SliderItem> {
            new SliderItem
            {
                ImageUrl = "1.jpg",
                Name = "Test 1"
             },
            new SliderItem
            {
                 ImageUrl = "2.jpg",
                Name="Test 2"
            }
        };

        this.BindingContext = this;
```

The Label will keep empty and i cannot find the problem.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Android or iOS? Seems this is working good in iOS in my end.

Comment: Both ... the code just dont show anything. it makes not really sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try to populate the list before  InitializeComponent()